# Select rows based on 5% of total ticket count per combo of User/Team/Category

Tags: ms-access

I am fairly new to the world of programming and am self-taught. From everything I've read I think I need code that includes the use of sub-queries. However, I've never created any sub-queries so I'm a little lost on how to accomplish that.

I have a table that include multiple tickets entered by different users for specific teams and categories. I need to count the # of tickets per combinations and then pull back a random no of tickets (5 %) based on each combination.

For example the combo of Smith,SamL&CInquiry has 176 tickets, I need to pull 9 of those tickets

The combo of Brown,TomL&CLicensing has 22 tickets, I need to pull 1 of those.

I am attempting to do this in Access database.

Here's what I've tried:

```
Public Function Test() 
Set dbs = CurrentDb 
Dim newqry As QueryDef 
Set newqry = dbs.CreateQueryDef(rst2) i = 1 i2 = 1 
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("Query1", dbOpenDynaset) 
Do Until i2 > i 
   rst.Move Int(Rnd(rst.RecordCount) * 100) 
   If i2 = 1 Then 
     query_filter_store = " where combo ='" & rst.combo.Value & "'" 
   Else 
     query_filter_store = query_filter_store & " or " & "combo='" & rst.combo.Value & "'" 
   End If 
i2 = i2 + 1 
Loop 
'Set rst2 = dbs.OpenRecordset("select * from query1" & query_filter_store) 
Set rst2 = dbs.CreateQueryDef("test_query", "select * from query1 " & query_filter_store)
```

Comment: access and mysql are 2 different beasts

Comment: Tried

Public Function Test()


Set dbs = CurrentDb

Dim newqry As QueryDef
Set newqry = dbs.CreateQueryDef(rst2)


i = 1
i2 = 1
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("Query1", dbOpenDynaset)
Do Until i2 > i
rst.Move Int(Rnd(rst.RecordCount) * 100)
If i2 = 1 Then
query_filter_store = " where combo ='" & rst.combo.Value & "'"
Else
query_filter_store = query_filter_store & " or " & "combo='" & rst.combo.Value & "'"
End If
i2 = i2 + 1
Loop
'Set rst2 = dbs.OpenRecordset("select * from query1" & query_filter_store)

Set rst2 = dbs.CreateQueryDef("test_query", "select * from query1 " & query_filter_store)

Comment: That code was created with the help a programmer here at work. It only returned 1 combo and all of the combo's tickets instead of 5%

Comment: I suppose it doesn't have to be a sub-query - that was just what I kept finding over the last 3 days as I googled. Plus that was the hint the programmer that is helping me learn gave me.

Comment: I totally apologize if I listed the wrong hashtag. This was my first attempt at using a discussion board. I am going to make many mistakes at asking for help.

Comment: We need some sample data and see your schema.

Comment: Thank you all for taking the time to review my question. I think I shouldn't have posted here as I am not a programmer and probably can't answer the questions that will be asked. Please delete my question.

Comment: You have to delete it yourself.